# How to properly load a picture into a UITableVIew

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to retrieve a user profile photo like this inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
    let profileImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"http://website.com/something/somethingelse-pic/\(self.userArray[indexPath.row]).jpg")!)!)
```

I'm just wondering if there is a better and faster way to do this because this seem to load pretty slow and laggy.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage is a good choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async to load image from URL

```
       let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
       let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
       NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                // Store the image in to our cache
                self.imageCache[urlString] = image
                // Update the cell
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                         cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                // println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
       })
```

Ref: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-part-5-async-image-loading-and-caching/